# Unitary linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

So my professor gave me this question :

> Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$, $T\colon V\to V$ be a linear map and $\forall 1\leq i \leq n$  $\|T(e_{i})\|=1$. Is $T$ unitary ?

So I know that there is a counterexample. But I have a proof and I would like to know what is wrong in it. So we know that 
for all $i$
$$\sqrt{\langle T(e_{i}),T(e_{i})\rangle}=1$$
therefore 
$$\langle T(e_{i}),T(e_{i})\rangle=1$$
therefore
$$\langle e_{i},T^{*}(T(e_{i}))\rangle=1$$
and we know that
$\langle e_{i},e_{i}\rangle=1$, therefore $T^{*}T=I_{n}$, in the same way I can proof that $TT^{*}=I_{n}$.

And that is it. I proved $T$ is unitary.

Where is my mistake ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax. Some specific tips: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for *that meaning only*. When you want angle brackets, you need to use `\langle` and `\rangle`. To get an arrow $\to$, you can use `\to` or `\rightarrow`. For an arrow $\implies$ (which means "implies" or "therefore"), you can use `\implies`, or `\Rightarrow` for a shorter version. To get the square root of `stuff`, write `\sqrt{stuff}`.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks !! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, from $\def\lr#1{\langle #1\rangle}$$\lr{e_i, T^*Te_i}=1$ and $\lr{e_i,e_i} = 1$ for all $i$, you cannot conclude that $T^*Te_i = e_i$! We have that $\lr{e_i, T^*Te_i - e_i} = 0$, which means that $T^*Te_i - e_i$ must be orthogonal to $e_i$ (all $i$). But is doesn't have to be 0, for that we need the stronger assumption $\lr{e_j, T^*Te_i - e_i} = 0$ for all $j$ (not just for $j=i$), or $\lr{e_j, T^*Te_i} = \lr{e_j, e_i}$, for all $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $B=I\iff \forall i,j\,\langle Be_i,e_j\rangle=1$.

So your proof boils down to prove that $\forall i\,\langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle=1$ (i.e. all diagonal elements of the matrix $A$ are equal to $1$) implies $\forall i,j\,\langle Ae_i,e_j\rangle=1$  (i.e. all elements of the matrix $A$ are equal to $1$), which is clearly impossible.